# ListModel , QMap, Xml parsing

Tags: qt, parsing, qmap

i am trying to parse some car2go response xml and create my c++ model. then expose that model to qml.

Question: which map to use Qmap or qmultimap ? and how to parse ?

so looks car2go response :
http://code.google.com/p/car2go/wiki/vehicles_v2_0

THanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do it much easier than that. There are 2 ways:

1) Use XmlListModel and specify the xml option as a path

2) Since JSON is supported, use AJAX technique - use XmlHttpRequest in QML and post a request to the server and operate on your JSON object by getting it using JSON.parse(xml_http_request.responseText)

Comment: thank you Barbaris. I have already implemented the xmllistmodel version. But i want to edit received data and then display it. Qjson is really nice but don't want to add extra library.